# Find if widget block is active

Tags: widgets, block-editor

I'm used to check if a widget from installed my plugin is active.

With the new block editor extending to widgets in WordPress 5.8, I was wondering if there is a way to check the widget block that I created (both old php-based and gutenberg-based widgets are installed by my plugin) is activated by the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One could e.g. get the widget blocks data with:

```
$widget_blocks = get_option( 'widget_block' );
```

and then loop through the array and run [has_block()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/) on the contant part, e.g. like (untested):

```
function is_active_block_widget_wpse( $blockname )
    $widget_blocks = get_option( 'widget_block' );
    foreach( (array) $widget_blocks as $widget_block ) {
        if ( ! empty( $widget_block['content'] ) 
             && has_block( $blockname, $widget_block['content'] ) 
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to find if a given blockname is an active widget:

```
is_active_block_widget_wpse( 'my-plugin/my-block' )
```

We note that this simple implementation assumes none *inactive* block widgets.

Other helpful functions: [wp_get_sidebars_widgets()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_sidebars_widgets/) and [is_active_widget()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_active_widget/)